# Limit access to AKS cluster IP from internal Azure traffic

Tags: azure-aks, azure-nsg

How to limit access to AKS cluster IP from internal Azure traffic using NSG on the load balancer/application gateway?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the access to your AKS via setting authorized IP address with:

```
# Existing Cluster
az aks update \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges  73.140.245.0/24
    
# New Cluster
az aks create \
  --name MyAKSCluster \
  --resource-group MyResourceGroup \
  --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges  73.140.245.0/24
```

Your can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/api-server-authorized-ip-ranges) good documentation.

NOTE: this will only affect accessing yoour cluster with kubectl etc, deplyoment pipelines etc.

If you are talking about limiting the access to your ingress controller, please leave a comment.